# Strange behavior of Highchart tool tip

Tags: hover, tooltip, highlight, highcharts

The tooltip in my Highchart is behaving strangely. It is living its own life. It doesn't show the tooltip of the point on which I hover, but shows the tooltip of any point randomly.

Here is a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/AeV7h/9/

```
$(function () {

var data=[[28,0],[24,3],[16,10]];
var param= { WodTag: "cur_spd", Name: "Current speed", Color: "#C6C6C6", LineStyle: "Solid", SeriesType: "line", LineWidth: 2, TickInterval: null,  MinValue: null, MaxValue: null, Decimals: 2 };

$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            height: 700,
            width: 400,
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBorderColor: '#E4E4E4',
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                useHTML: true,
                text: param.Name + "( m/s  )",
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            min: param.MinValue,
            max: param.MaxValue,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
            tickInterval: param.TickInterval
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Depth(m)',
            },
            reversed: true,
            tickLength: 50,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot'
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: param.Name,
            data: data,
            color: param.Color,
            dashStyle: param.LineStyle,
            lineWidth: param.LineWidth,
            type: "line"
        }]
    });
});
```

Can anyone help and tell me why it is behaving like this, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that your data is not sorted by increasing X value. If you read the `Series.data` documentation it says that ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data)):

> Note data must be sorted by X in order for the tooltip positioning and data grouping to work.

You should always sort your data like this before handing it over to Highcharts. Highcharts doesn't sort any data. Doing it by hand for your example your data should look like this:

```
var data=[[16,10],[24,3],[28,0]];
```

As in [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/AeV7h/10/), and everything works as intended.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for response. I tried it, and it works great. But There is one problem, we need to show data in order that its sorted by Y. Is there any way to get the tooltip working fine, if I have data sorted by Y. (Sorted by depth in my example)

Comment: reverted the order of x and Y in data, and sorted it by X. And then inverted the chart, which solved the problem. Is there any other way too ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need?  Not understanding the problem (possibly a new question)